# Primefaces gmap add a marker

Tags: google-maps, jsf, primefaces

I want to add add labels to a gmap of primefaces. That functionality is not provided in primefeces. So I wanted to integrate gmap with google javascript. THen I will be able to add labels to my gmap.

For a test I added the following code.

It tries to add a simple marker to a map generated from primefaces gmap component. But this code is not working. Where is the error?

```
            <h:form >
                <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDnIF053oCwO1848mAvz6-N6eSeOeD8BaI&amp;callback=initMap" type="text/javascript" ></script> 
                <div id="map" >
                    <p:gmap id="gmap" widgetVar="w_gmap" 
                            center="#{notificationController.mohArea.centreLatitude},#{notificationController.mohArea.centreLongitude}" zoom="#{notificationController.mohArea.zoomLavel}" 
                            type="ROADMAP" style="width:900px;height:600px;border: 1px solid black;" 
                            streetView="true"
                            model="#{notificationController.polygonModel}">
                    </p:gmap>
                </div>
                <script >
                    function initMap() {
                        var mypos = {lat: #{notificationController.mohArea.centreLatitude}, lng: #{notificationController.mohArea.centreLongitude}};
                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map');
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: mypos,
                            map: map
                        });
                    }
                </script>
```

Comment: Well I didn't try your code, but from a first look I noticed that you are accessing the widgetVar in the wrong namespace, as the widget var name is `w_gmap`, you should access it like this `PF('w_gmap')`, and I can't see where are you calling the initMap function ? you might want to call that in the document.ready, with a latency of one second maybe just to make sure the widgetVar is ready.

Comment: Edited the question accordingly